# Function receiving all variables before make operations on them?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I have problem with function receiving multiple variables and THEN do operations on them. Lets make simple example:

```
function first(){
    var one = 1;
    result(one); // I mean it should be result(one, null); but I want to pass second variable later
}

//lets assume function first get some asyns operations...
setTimeout(function(){
    first();
}, 2000);

function second(){
    var two = 2;
    result(two); // should be result(null, two), but one will be passed after a 2 seconds and I want to sum them
}

second();

function result(one, two){
    var ultraHardMath = one + two;
}
```

So the thing is I want to wait till result() receive all needed variables (one and two) before I move further with ultraHardMath. How to do that?

Comment: you may want to look into `Promise.all` and `then`

Comment: Use promises! :-)

Comment: I head about the promises, but is there any way to do this without promises and async (modules)?

Comment: @webmasternewbie Yes, but it's super-complicated. Basically you have to use flags to remember which values were already passed, and executed your logic when everything is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the passed in arguments in the function itself (`this`) and then execute the logic of the function once all arguments are accounted for:

```
function result(one, two) {
  if (one !== undefined) this.one = one;
  if (two !== undefined) this.two = two;
  if (this.one === undefined || this.two === undefined) return;
  var ultraHardMath = this.one + this.two;
}
```

That works by omitting trailing arguments or by passing `undefined` to the arguments you don't want to provide:

```
result(undefined, 2);
...
result(1);
```

That logic can be generalized to a function that "recalls" passed in arguments and calls the original function when all arguments are accounted for. It's a kind of partial application that also cares about arguments provided "in the middle":

```
// returns a function that recalls arguments passed to function fn
// calls fn when the number of arguments recalled reaches n
function recall(fn, n) {
  var stored = []; // recalled arguments
  return function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    // store the passed in arguments
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
      if (args[i] !== undefined) stored[i] = args[i];
    }
    // check if all arguments are accounted for
    if (stored.length < n) return;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (stored[i] === undefined) return;
    }
    // call the original function with the stored arguments
    return fn.apply(null, stored);
  };
}
```

Now, having that, your function can be left untouched, but just replaced by its "recalling" version:

```
var result = function(one, two) {
  var ultraHardMath = one + two;
}
result = recall(result, 2);
```

It works the same way as before:

```
result(undefined, 2);
...
result(1);
```

`recall` can be simplified a bit:

```
function recall(fn, n) {
  var stored = [];
  return function() {
    var all = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (arguments[i] !== undefined) stored[i] = arguments[i];
      if (stored[i] === undefined) all = false;
    }
    if (all) return fn.apply(null, stored);
  };
}
```

Comment: Very interesting idea! And well described. My problem atm is that I have many asynchronous functions (for simplicity lets say they are all requests) 5 or 6. And they work in background getting the data. My main function is run almost at the beginning - and it main purpose is to receive data from those requests (functions) and make some adjustments. Problem is that it run, when it receive first data element. I want it to store ALL the data in it (it can take long time, cause some of the requests are much slower then rest) and then execute whole function (it simply passing data to render).

Comment: I did mark this as accepted answer, cause it's well described and much easier to add additional results elements. Everything is working perfect but I ended with promises after all :) - easier error handling. @Jordão kudos! BTW@Pankaj Shukla answer was good, but I had real mindfuck when trying to add more functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:
It uses closure concept, so that result function could wait.
Is this what you are looking for?

```js
(function () {
            var funcFoo;
            function first() {
                var one = 1;
                funcFoo(one); // I mean it should be result(one, null); but I want to pass second variable later
            }
    
            //lets assume function first get some asyns operations...
            setTimeout(function () {
                first();
            }, 2000);
    
            function second() {
                var two = 2;
                funcFoo = result(two); // should be result(null, two), but one will be passed after a 2 seconds and I want to sum them
            }
    
            second();
    
            function result(two) {
                return function foo(one) {
                    var ultraHardMath = one + two;
                    console.log(ultraHardMath);
                }
            }
        })();
```